# messagedialogs on monodevelop

Tags: c#, winforms, monodevelop

i'm creating a winforms application on monodevelop but i've problem on programming messagedialogs yes/no, in particular:

```
Gtk.Window main = new Gtk.Window ("MessageDialog");
            MessageDialog question = new MessageDialog(main, 
                                                       DialogFlags.Modal,
                                                       MessageType.Question, 
                                                       ButtonsType.YesNo, "Are you sure you want to quit?");
            question.Title="CsoundConverter";
            ResponseType response = (ResponseType)question.Run();

            question.Show();

            if (response == ResponseType.Yes)
           {                  
            // some statements
            question.Destroy();
           }

            if (response == ResponseType.Yes)
          {
            //some statements
            question.Destroy();
          }
```

What's wrong in this code?

Comment: You tell us. What is not working in your code?

Comment: at runtime when it's fired the event which calls that messagedialog, the debugging stops

Comment: Which line specifically? Is there an exception?

Comment: in the application output there is this report: (process:126): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:126): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(process:126): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(
(process:126): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2715: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:126): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SECOND ANSWER:**

Try not casting the `MessageDialog.Run()` return as a `ResponseType`. Leave it as an `int`:

```
int response = question.Run();
```

I am assuming that you are using Gnome MessageDialog.

see my reply to your comment below

**FIRST ANSWER:**
Should your second If statement not be:

```
if (response == ResponseType.No)
{
    //some statements
    question.Destroy()
}
```

I would also think that this should be an If/Else.

Comment: i changed the responseType to "ResponseType.No" but doesn't work again

Comment: Looking up Gnome MessageDialog, it shows that `MessageDialog.Run()` returns an `int` to specify the response action. Additionally `ResponseType` is simply `Enumeration` of `integers`. Would it not make sense to just check the return by: `int response = question.Run();`

Comment: and how i check if the response is yes or not in the If istructions?

Comment: The same way you are now. ResponseType.Yes is just a const of type int.